# it can't read property 'id' of undefined but I have some values in it, and don't why it should be unknown

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm using *React ContextApi* to manage the state components.
I have some files in my `data.js`, which has refused to display on the `Details.js` page.

I know something's wrong but it's not showing me any error code and its not displaying instead its writing `"Cannot read property 'id' of undefined"`

[image]

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { storeProducts, detailProduct } from './data';

const BookContext = React.createContext()
   class BookProvider extends Component {
   state = {
        products: [...storeProducts],
        details: detailProduct
    };

    componentDidMount() {
    this.setProducts();
}

setProducts = () => {
    let products = [];
    storeProducts.forEach(item => {
        const singleItem = {...item};
        products = [...products, singleItem];
    });

    this.setState(() => {
        return {products}
    });
};

handleDetail = () => {
    console.log("Hello from detail")
};
addToCart = () => {
    console.log("Hello from add to cart")
};
render() {
    return (
        <BookContext.Provider value={{
            // products: this.state.products,
            // details: this.state.details,
            // Destructuring all the values that is in the state property
            ...this.state,
            handleDetail: this.handleDetail,
            addToCart: this.addToCart
        }}>
            {this.props.children}
        </BookContext.Provider>
    )
}
};

const BookConsumer = BookContext.Consumer;

export { BookProvider, BookConsumer };

This is the Details.js file on the project
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BookConsumer } from '../context';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { ButtonContainer } from './Button';

 class Details extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <BookConsumer>
                {(value) => {
                    const {id, company, img, price, title, info, inCart} = 
                          value.detailProduct;
                    return (
                        <div className="container py-5">
                            {/* TITLE */}
                            <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-10 mx-auto text-center 
text-slanted text-blue my-5">
                                <h1>{title}</h1>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    )
                }}
            </BookConsumer>
        );
    }
}

export default Details;
```

Comment: Can you share the code of `BookProvider`?

Comment: Please post text, not images of text. You may also want to check out various resources on how to ask good questions as there are few details here anyone can use to help.

Comment: look I cant paste it all

Comment: Okay thank you I will post text

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `value` argument doesn't have a property `detailProduct` set. Check it first.

Comment: it has in the data.js in json's format. Let me show the full code

Answer (score 1):

You are destructuring `value.detailProduct` instead of `value.details`.

Indeed in `context.js`,

```
value={{
            ...this.state,
            handleDetail: this.handleDetail,
            addToCart: this.addToCart
        }}
```

and `state` has no `detailProduct` key.

Comment: Yeah... but it will work. I feel the error it's popping out as a result of Details.js

Comment: Yes because you descructure `value` in `Details.js` so the error is happening in that file. I don't get what is your interrogation ?

Comment: had to destructure it to get all that was in data.js

Comment: As you can see, the error is not at all related to `data.js` itself but by a operation you're doing afterwards where you're requesting a key that does not exist in an object.